# Dropdown menu closes when i click it (anywhere)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu with a login/register form, but when i try to click the form content, the menu closes.

I tried to do something with Javascript that it only closes when i click the "X" button but i wasnt sucessful. Here's the code:

[with the hamburguer menu closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SphIb.png)

[with the hamburguer menu open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SphIb.png)

```js
function animaIcon(x){
 x.classList.toggle("change");
}

function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

$('.container').on('click', function() {
 if ($('.dropdown-content').css('opacity')==0) $('.dropdown-content').css('opacity', 0.95);
 else $('.dropdown-content').css('opacity', 0);
});
```

```css
/* HAMBURGUER MENU */

.icone-menu {
 width: 100%;
 float: right;
 padding: 18px 8%;
}
.container {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 background-color: #111;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 margin-top: -55px;
 margin-left: -310px;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-content a {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 150%;
 color: white;
 padding: 100px 18px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
.down-botao a {
 color: #11E77C;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.dropdown-content button {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 40%;
 margin-left: 15px;
 font-weight: bolder;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background-color: black;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #dd3910;
 color: white;
}
.modal {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 400px;
 padding: 30px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 min-height: 420px;
}
.tab {
 float: left;
 &:first-of-type {
 margin-right: 15px;
}
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
 color: #13c7ae;
}
.show {
 display: block;
}
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 6px auto;
 transition: 0.4s;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1000
}
.change .bar1 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
 transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}
.change .bar2 {
 opacity: 0;
}
.change .bar3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<nav class="icone-menu">
<a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="crossagenda" class="logo-mobile"></a>
<div class="container" onclick="animaIcon(this), myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">What</a></li>
      <li class="down-botao"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="sign-in" name="options" class="option" checked/>
        <label for="sign-in">Sign in</label>
        <form action="#" class="form">
          <p class="float-label">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
          </p>
          <p class="float-label">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign me in"/>
          </p>
          <div class="forgot"> <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a> </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="sign-up" name="options" class="option"/>
        <label for="sign-up">Sign up</label>
        <form action="#" class="form">
          <p class="float-label">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          </p>
          <p class="float-label">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          </p>
          <p class="float-label">
            <label for="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm password"/>
          </p>
          <p class="toggle">
            <label for="accept">
              <input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept"/>
              I accept the <a href="#">Terms &amp; Services</a></label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign me up"/>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Until you are comfortable with both, try using jQuery or JavaScript only. It's easy to mix jQuery and plain objects together and get them confused. I'm not sure if you already have or not, I'm just glancing. If you have multiple states from more than 2 classes, I suggest that you use `add/remove`  methods instead of `toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function animaIcon(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  $('.modal').toggle();
}

$('.container').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.dropdown-content').css('opacity') == 0) $('.dropdown-content').css('opacity', 0.95);
  else $('.dropdown-content').css('opacity', 0);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
/* HAMBURGUER MENU */

.icone-menu {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  padding: 18px 8%;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  /*display: none;*/
  background-color: #111;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: -55px;
  margin-left: -310px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
  padding: 100px 18px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.down-botao a {
  color: #11E77C;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.dropdown-content button {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #dd3910;
  color: white;
}
.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  min-height: 420px;
  display: none;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
tab:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: #13c7ae;
}
.show {
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="icone-menu">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="crossagenda" class="logo-mobile">
  </a>
  <div class="container" onclick="animaIcon(this), myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">What</a>
        </li>
        <li class="down-botao"><a href="#">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="sign-in" name="options" class="option" checked />
      <label for="sign-in">Sign in</label>
      <form action="#" class="form">
        <p class="float-label">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        </p>
        <p class="float-label">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Sign me in" />
        </p>
        <div class="forgot">
          <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="sign-up" name="options" class="option" />
      <label for="sign-up">Sign up</label>
      <form action="#" class="form">
        <p class="float-label">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </p>
        <p class="float-label">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </p>
        <p class="float-label">
          <label for="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
          <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm password" />
        </p>
        <p class="toggle">
          <label for="accept">
            <input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" />I accept the <a href="#">Terms &amp; Services</a>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Sign me up" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, what happens when i change the code is that the menu now flashes. It opens and closes immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening when a user clicks an element inside `.container`:

- The click event is trigger on the target element
- The event travels toward the root of the DOM, triggering itself on each element it finds along the way (the term "triggering" may be misleading; the event is only "triggered" once).
- When it gets to `.container`, your callback function is invoked and the drop-down menu is collapsed.

To resolve this issue, make sure any click events for elements within `.container` (that you would like to *NOT* trigger the drop-down menu's collapse) stop propagation of that event.

```
$('.container .buttons').on('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do whatever
});
```

Comment: I understand the logic you explained. But something wrong happens when i try to implement it.
This error appears: VM1274 index.html?username=&password=:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: animaIcon is not defined(…)

animaIcon is the function that makes the hamburguer icon animate. But even if i delete it, the error appears to other functions. And this only happens when i put the code you wrote.

I edited the first post with the updated JS code.

Comment: looks like I left out a parenthesis. Sorry about that, I freehanded it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, was able to fix it using this javascript code:

```js
$( "#btn-menu" ).click(function() {
   $(".dropdown-content").toggle("slow");
 });
```